# Бинарное дерево. Утечка памяти.

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Есть структура дерева:

```
struct Tree {
    int value;
    Tree* left;
    Tree* right;
    Tree(int v) {
        value = v;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    Tree() {
        value = 0;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
};
```

Также есть функция добавления нового узла:

```
bool AddNode(Tree* root, int data) {
    if(root) {
        if(data < root->value) { AddNode(root->left, data); }
        else if(data > root->value) { AddNode(root->right, data); }
        else { return false; }
    }
    else {
        root = new Tree(data);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Но почему-то вот в этой строчке происходит утечка памяти:

```
root = new Tree(data);
```

Освобождение памяти:

```
void DeleteTree(Tree* root) {
    if(root) {
        DeleteTree(root->left);
        DeleteTree(root->right);
        delete root;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём дело.

Comment: а как освобождаете ресурсы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же передаёте `root` по значению! Соответственно, если процедура его пытается изменить, эти изменения не видны за пределами процедуры, и вновь выделенное значение теряется. Ваше дерево будет пустым, элементы на самом деле не добавятся.

Пишите так:

```
bool AddNode(Tree** ppRoot, int data) {
    if(*ppRoot) {
        Tree* pRoot = *ppRoot;
        if(data < pRoot->value) { AddNode(&(pRoot->left), data); }
        else if(data > pRoot->value) { AddNode(&(pRoot->right), data); }
        else { return false; }
    }
    else {
        *ppRoot = new Tree(data);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: согласен нужно добавить деструктор в структуру

Comment: да, вот весь main:

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    Tree* root = new Tree;
    int data;
    cout << "Enter integer data to build a tree:\n";
    while(true) {
        cin >> data;
        if(cin.fail()) {
            cout << "Data entry is completed\n";
            cin.clear();
            break;
        }
        AddNode(root, data);
    }
    DeleteTree(root);
    return 0;
}

Comment: т.е. вместо 

    DeleteTree(root);

нужно использовать

    DeleteTree(&root);

а в функции принимать указатель на указатель?

Comment: Угу, и в AddNode тоже.

Comment: @devnikor: кстати, в DeleteTree как раз можно и по значению.